# Left alignment of comment "ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException" breaks coding style

Tags: resharper

Whenever there is a possible null reference exception, Resharper suggests to check, assert or suppress the warning with these comments:

```
// ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
            objectWhichCouldBeNull.DoSomething();
// ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
```

However, the comments are always indented on the way to the left edge of the source code document. Is there a way to keep the comments aligned with other code, especially when using Resharper Code Cleanup function (Ctrl-Alt-F)?

Here's how it should be:

```
            // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
            objectWhichCouldBeNull.DoSomething();
            // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other | Other | Don't indent comments started at first column`

Comment: Sorry. Just tried that is not working. Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper 10.0.1.